# saveWorkbook in the xlsx package doesn’t let me to save the sheets that I created

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, rjava

I am using the package ‘xlsx’ in R to create and save an Excel file with several sheets. You can see below how I create and save the file. However, it is not working most of the time. It gave me the following error:

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
>   cl,  :
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to
>   save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part
>   /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@4bb4de6a

```
library(gridExtra) ; library(grid) ; library(tidyr) ; library(reshape2) ; library(plyr) ; library(lubridate) ; library(xlsx) ;  require(rJava) 

var<-0
var[1]<-'HAA5'
var[2]<-'SWTR'
var[3]<-'TTHM'
data1<-read.csv('AllData.csv')
analys10<-createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
for (i in 1:3) {
IM<-as.character(var[i])
sheet10=createSheet(analys10, IM)
sub<-data1[data1$ANALYTE_NAME==IDs[i],]
subdata<-sub[,1:19]
subdata<-unique(subdata)
subs<-subdata[!is.na(subdata$MCL_VALUE),]
n<-nrow(subs)
for (j in 1:n) {
if (as.character(subs$MCL_UOM[j])==as.character(subs$RESULT_UOM[j]))
subs$mag[j]<-(subs$RESULT[j]-subs$MCL_VALUE[j])/subs$MCL_VALUE[j]
}
subs$analysis10<-ifelse(subs$mag >10, 'Yes','no')    
summary10<- ddply(subs, c("WATER_SYSTEM_NAME","analysis10",'year'),  summarise, N= length(analysis10))
sum10<-summary10[summary10$analysis10  %in% 'Yes',]
table10<-reshape(sum10, timevar="year", idvar=c("WATER_SYSTEM_NAME","analysis10"), direction="wide" )
table10$analysis10<- NULL
table10<-table10[,order(colnames(table10),decreasing=TRUE)]
addDataFrame(table10, sheet=sheet10, startColumn=1, row.names=FALSE)
}
saveWorkbook(analys10, "analys10.xlsx")
```

I spend the last whole day to figure out what is the problem but I had no chance so far. Any suggestions?
I added the whole code and a sample data set. Hopefully it will work!

```
PWS_ID  REGULATING_AGENCY   WATER_SYSTEM_NAME   CITY    Counties_Served Owner_Type  ANALYTE_NAME    PWS_Type    Primary_Source  POPULATION  Quarter MCL_VALUE   MCL_UOM XMOD    RESULT  RESULT_UOM  VIOL_BEGIN_DATE Size_toggle year    VIOL_END_DATE   ADDRESS
210001  DIS LAKE    ARN AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2017 Q4 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.0758  MG/L    10/1/2017   Smaller 2017    12/31/2017  P.O. Bo
210001  DIS LAKE    ARN AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2016 Q4 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.07    MG/L    10/1/2016   Smaller 2016    12/31/2016  P.O. B
210001  DIS ALPINE  ARN AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2017 Q1 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.095   MG/L    1/1/2017    Smaller 2017    3/31/2017   P.O. B
210001  DIS ALPINE  ARNOLD  AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2017 Q3 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.086   MG/L    7/1/2017    Smaller 2017    9/30/2017   P.O. B
210001  DIS ALPINE  ARNOLD  AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2012 Q3 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.0658  MG/L    7/1/2012    Smaller 2012    9/30/2012   P.O. B
210001  DIS ALPINE  ARNOLD  AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2016 Q3 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.062   MG/L    7/1/2016    Smaller 2016    9/30/2016   P.O. B
210001  DIS ALPINE  ARNOLD  AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2650    2017 Q2 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.096   MG/L    4/1/2017    Smaller 2017    6/30/2017   P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q4 NA      NA  NA      12/1/2012   Smaller 2012    12/31/2012  P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q4 NA      NA  NA      11/1/2012   Smaller 2012    11/30/2012  P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q4 NA      NA  NA      12/1/2012   Smaller 2012    12/31/2012  P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AL  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q4 NA      NA  NA      12/1/2012   Smaller 2012    12/31/2012  P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AM  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q3 NA      NA  NA      8/1/2012    Smaller 2012    8/31/2012   P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AM  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q3 NA      NA  NA      8/1/2012    Smaller 2012    8/31/2012   P.O. B
300037  DIS JACKSON     IONE    AM  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   2000    2012 Q4 NA      NA  NA      11/1/2012   Smaller 2012    11/30/2012  P.O. B
310002  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  TTHM    Comm    Surface water   6420    2017 Q1 0.08    MG/L    NA  0.084   MG/L    1/1/2017    Smaller 2017    3/31/2017   P.O. B
310004  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  TTHM    Comm    Surface water   1060    2017 Q2 0.08    MG/L    NA  0.081   MG/L    4/1/2017    Smaller 2017    6/30/2017   P.O. B
310005  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  HAA5    Comm    Surface water   846 2014 Q3 0.08    MG/L    NA  0.0815  MG/L    7/1/2014    Smaller 2014    9/30/2014   P.O. B
310011  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  SWTR    Comm    Surface water   838 2016 Q3 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.065   MG/L    7/1/2016    Smaller 2016    9/30/2016   P.O. B
310011  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  SWTR    Comm    Surface water   838 2017 Q1 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.068   MG/L    1/1/2017    Smaller 2017    3/31/2017   P.O. B
310011  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  SWTR    Comm    Surface water   838 2016 Q2 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.069   MG/L    4/1/2016    Smaller 2016    6/30/2016   P.O. B
310012  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON AM  Pr  TTHM    Comm    Surface water   18544   2016 Q4 0.08    MG/L    NA  0.094   MG/L    10/1/2016   Larger  2016    12/31/2016  P.O. B
400073  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON BUT Pr  SWTR    Comm    Ground water    66  2017 Q3 10  MG/L    NA  11  MG/L    7/1/2017    Smaller 2017    7/31/2017   P.O. B
510012  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON BUT Pr  SWTR    Comm    Surface water   180 2016 Q2 0.06    MG/L    NA  0.067   MG/L    4/1/2016    Smaller 2016    6/30/2016   P.O. B
600008  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON BUT Pr  SWTR    Comm    Ground water    381 2012 Q1 10  UG/L    NA  26.1    UG/L    1/1/2012    Smaller 2012    3/31/2012   P.O. B
600008  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON BUT Pr  SWTR    Comm    Ground water    381 2014 Q4 10  UG/L    NA  23.6    UG/L    10/1/2014   Smaller 2014    12/31/2014  P.O. B
600008  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON BUT Pr  SWTR    Comm    Ground water    381 2015 Q4 NA      NA  24  UG/L    10/1/2015   Smaller 2015    12/31/2015  P.O. B
600008  DIS JACKSON     JACKSON BUT Pr  SWTR    Comm    Ground water    381 2013 Q2 10  UG/L    NA  24.6    UG/L    4/1/2013    Smaller 2013    6/30/2013   P.O. B
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where your code is breaking, but here's an example that works. I've used the built-in `mtcars` data frame for illustration:

```
library(xlsx)

var = c('HAAS','SWTR','TTHM')
analys10 <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

for (i in var) {
  sheet = createSheet(analys10, i)
  addDataFrame(mtcars, sheet=sheet, startColumn=1, row.names=FALSE)
}

saveWorkbook(analys10, "analys10.xlsx")
```

In your actual code, I assume you're adding a different data frame each time through the loop, so it's possible something is going wrong in the way you're setting up or choosing each data frame, but it's difficult to tell without additional information.

Comment: Even the code that you wrote give me the same error.                    Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@7e9a5fbe

Comment: The issue may be something to do with Java or R's interaction with Java, but I'm not sure.